# Does this pattern has a name?

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if this pattern has a well-known name that I'm not aware of.

```js
function PATTERN_NAME(val) {
    return typeof val === 'function' ? val() : val;
}
```

I don't know if the term `pattern` is correct here. Just wondering how this kind of function is normally named.

---

Example of usage:

Let's say that this class receive a settings argument with something like this:

```
interface Settings {
  header: () => string | string
}
```

Then you can, in some instances just pass a static string value to be always used, but in other uses, you pass a callback that may return different header values depending on when it's used.

You can just call this PATTERN_NAME whenever you want to display the header

```js
console.log(PATTERN_NAME(settings.header))
```

Comment: I wouldn't even consider this a pattern tbh

Comment: Not sure what you mean but maybe a callback?

Comment: `val()` is a [Higher-Order Function](https://eloquentjavascript.net/05_higher_order.html) call.

Comment: I think he's asking about the pattern where you call it if it's a callback, but returning it if it's an ordinary value.

Comment: It's not remarkable.  The ternary operator `?:` is there so that the function doesn't explode if no "callback" function is assigned to `val`.

Comment: @JoseTruyol van val be number/string/whatever ot is't `function | undefined`?

Comment: @Dimava It can be `function | object | string | number | boolean | undefined`

Answer (score -1):

If `val` is `T | () => T`, it's a common pattern, often used for generics initialization (I don't know how it's named)

```
function instantiate<T>(stucture: {data: MaybeInstantiator<T>}) : {data: T} {
   if (typeof stucture.data == 'function')
      return {data: stucture.data()}
   else 
      return {data: stucture.data }
}
```

---

There are alike well-known constructs,

```
type MaybeRef<T> = T | Ref<T>; // vue framework
type MaybePromise<T> = T | Promise<T>;
```

so this MaybeShould be called MaybeConstructor or MaybeInitializer or something alike

---

If `val` is `function | undefined | null`,
This is called "optional call", and it's written as

```
function OPTIONAL_CALL(val) {
    return val?.()
}
```

(i.e. it's a language feature in modern JS)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

If `val` may have other types, it's generally called "bad code"

Fore more specific info, provide some real-life usages of a such function

Comment: 1.  That's a different operator.  2.  It's a different operation.  This operator is designed to facilitate method chaining when one or more methods in the chain could be null or undefined. 
 Method chaining is more difficult to do with the Ternary Operator.

Comment: Optional chaining is conditional on whether the value is undefined/null, not whether it's a function.

Comment: Can you provide some real-life uses for it? Question is too broad, this is the best answer I have for it's current form

Comment: The article Dimava linked does have a couple of examples.

Comment: I updated the question with a use case scenario

Comment: Yes, there is, lemme find it

Comment: Mkay, there is such a pattern, and it's commonly used (generally for initializers), but I don't know how it's called

Comment: @JoseTruyol I guess it may start with "Maybe" same as alike constructs, added info on that